# ¿Como detectar el color de fondo de una seccion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, scss

tengo una duda muy grande y no encontre nada en internet. Me gustaria poder detectar el color de backgorund o la section en la que estoy posicionado en mi pagina para poder cambiar el color de mi navbar.

La pagina la estoy desarrollando con React.js y utilizo SCSS.

El navbar es de un blanco claro y el fondo con el que tengo el problema es un azul y no tiene mucho contraste el contenido del navbar con el fondo de esa section. Por lo que pense en:

1- Detectar el color de fondo con SCSS.
2- Detectar el color de fondo con JS.
3- Detectar la section que estoy viendo con JS o SCSS.
4- Detectar por medio del DOM la section.

Busque por todos lados y con todos los idiomas pero no consigo ninguna repuesta.

Comment: Cómo estás definiendo el color de cada sección? Podrías guardar el color de cada sección en un atributo "data" y leer eso desde JS. `<section data-color="#f00"></section>`. Para detectar donde estás posicionado podes utilizar [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: @azeós lo defino por medio de scss, si habia pensado en guardarlo asi pero el problema es que no se como identificar el momento en el que estoy posicionado en esa seccion

Comment: Publicá tu código SCSS y HTML así es más fácil ayudarte.